# Webview flash unknow error

Tags: android, flash, webview

I have a problem. I load a swf in a web view. My code look like this:

```
swf = new File(Config.FOLDER_DATA + msg.contenu_message);
uri = Uri.fromFile(swf);
web.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
web.setWebViewClient(new Web());
web.loadUrl(uri.toString());
```

Every damn time I have a lot of errors for no reason. The flash loads and works but these errors take all my debug page and I can't see real errors who block me. And maybe this is a real error who will block me later.

I can't get past the whole error code (thanks Eclipse logcat for an easy copy paste so I link an image of the log)

Any way to remove it or what do I need to change?

[image: Logcat]

Comment: you have a NullPointerException. I dont recognize the line so please post it...

Comment: I feel something is wrong with the swf. Is this swf playing through other apps in android like smartswf? 
I guess the rockship game swfs wont be played in android, Not sure thou.. check with other players and confirm

Comment: the fact is: the line is an android one i can't paste it

Comment: @blganesh101 it's work fine on smartswf

Comment: i had some doubt where u had stored the swf file

Comment: in my sdcard   
    Config.FolderData = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the flash plugin given by the constructor was the problem. 
I uninstall it and installe the official apk flash 11 ics. 
And since i have no more error